# Magento 1.9 Custom Entity, Can't retrieve entity config: eav/psdev_charity

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, module, magento-ce

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to save a model of type custom entity: Can't retrieve entity config: eav/psdev_charity. I suspect this is a problem with my configuration, however I'm so far unable to track it down. I'm on Magento 1.9 CE. Cache is disabled, developer mode is on, and I delete the contents of var prior to testing.

**Here's my my module's config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Psdev_Charity>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Psdev_Charity>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <psdev_charity>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Psdev_Charity</module>
                    <frontName>psdev_charity</frontName>
                </args>
            </psdev_charity>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
         <models>
             <psdev_charity>
                 <class>Psdev_Charity_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>charity_resource</resourceModel>
             </psdev_charity>
             <charity_resource>
                 <class>Psdev_Charity_Model_Resource</class>
                 <entities>
                     <psdev_charity>
                         <table>psdev_charity</table>
                     </psdev_charity>
                 </entities>
             </charity_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <charity_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Psdev_Charity</module>
                    <class>Psdev_Charity_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </charity_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Here's my model:**

```
class Psdev_Charity_Model_Charity extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('psdev_charity/charity');
    }
}
```

**Here's my Resource Model**

```
class Psdev_Charity_Model_Resource_Charity extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract 
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('psdev_charity');
        $this->setConnection(
            $resource->getConnection('charity_read'),
            $resource->getConnection('charity_write')
        );
    }
}
```

**Here's my collection**

```
<?php
class Psdev_Charity_Model_Resource_Charity_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->_init(
            'psdev_charity/charity',
            'psdev_charity/charity'
        );
    }
}
```

**Here's the controller where the error occurs. Error occurs at model->save()**

```
class Psdev_Charity_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{



    public function indexAction()
    {

        try {
            for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $model = Mage::getModel('psdev_charity/charity');
                $model->setCharityName('Donuts' . $i);
                $model->setCharityDescription('Round and Sugary');
                $model->setCharityImage('not an image link');
                $model->save();
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->loadLayout();

        $content = 'Fake charities have been created';
        $block = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
            ->setText($content);



        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);


        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Here's the Setup Class**

```
<?php
$installed = false;
$installer = $this;

try {

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addEntityType('psdev_charity', array(
    'entity_model' => 'psdev_charity',
    'table' => 'psdev_charity'
));

$installer->createEntityTables(
    $this->getTable('psdev_charity')
);

$installer->addAttribute('psdev_charity', 'charity_name', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Charity Name',
    'input' => 'text',
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'unique' => true,
    'is_visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_comparable' => false,
    'is_visible' => true,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
));

$installer->addAttribute('psdev_charity', 'charity_description', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Charity Description',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'is_visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_comparable' => false,
    'is_visible' => true,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
));

$installer->addAttribute('psdev_charity', 'charity_image', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Charity Image',
    'input' => 'image',
    'backend' => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'is_visible' => true,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'is_visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_comparable' => false,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
));

$installed = true;

} catch (Exception $e) {
$message = 'Could not complete Charity Module Installation: ' . $e->getMessage();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);
Mage::log($message);
}

if($installed === true) {
$message = 'Charity Module has been installed';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
Mage::log($message);
}


$installer->endSetup();
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be greatly appreciative. I'm finding it extremely difficult to troubleshoot, as there is only weak central documentation, and most of the data I can find is for a different version, or different specifics.

**Update: 10/30/2014**

It seems the error is thrown at model->save() but only if I try to set attributes. If I remove the calls (setCharityName()) the exception is not thrown, but of course, there is nothing in the database.

**Stack Trace**
Can't retrieve entity config: eav/psdev_charity

```
#0 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(277): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
#1 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(468): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackendTable()
#4 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(424): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->addAttribute(Object(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute))
#5 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(529): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->getAttribute('charity_descrip...')
#6 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1113): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->loadAllAttributes(Object(Psdev_Charity_Model_Charity))
#7 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Psdev_Charity_Model_Charity))
#8 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/community/Psdev/Charity/controllers/IndexController.php(17): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Psdev_Charity_IndexController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/paulsandel.com/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ha! found it, after a bit of trial error. The problem is in my setup class.

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addEntityType('psdev_charity', array(
   'entity_model' => 'psdev_charity',
   'table' => 'psdev_charity'
));
```

Should have been:

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addEntityType('psdev_charity', array(
 'entity_model' => 'psdev_charity/charity',
 'table' => 'psdev_charity/charity'
));
```

It seems I was trying to map directly to an entity and table, whereas I should have been mapping to my models.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your config file you should recheck syntex to define a model in config.xml and one more thing in config file you wrote this for model: `padev_charity` means your model should be in this dir structure under model directory `Psdev/Charity.php` and same will be applied for resource.php model and this should be under model directory in this structure `Charity/Resource.php` file.

So these model class will became  `Psdev_Charity_Model_Psdev_Charity` and second one will be similar based upon dir stucture.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however this doesn't seem accurate. All of my models are loading fine. Just not saving. It has something to do with the EAV attributes, though I've not confirmed this.

Comment: Plese use this code in your config file from 

`<psdev_charity>
<class>Psdev_Charity_Model</class>               <resourceModel>charity_resource</resourceModel>
</psdev_charity>`
  to 
`<charity>
<class>Psdev_Charity_Model_Charity</class>               <resourceModel>charity_resource</resourceModel>
</charity>`. 

Because you don't specify any class under model and also when you are using `Mage::getModel('psdev_charity/charity');` then it map your model in your config file so it will find `charity` model in config which is not present.